# Python - Automatically create new variables based on other variable

Tags: python

I would like to do something like this:

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    if i == 0:
        name_i = "A"
    elif i == 1:
        name_i = "B"
    else:
        name_i = "C"
```

to have name_o = "A", name_1 = "B", name_i = "C".

I know I cannot do it like that method but is there some **trick**  I can use to achieve that?

Comment: just put them in a list?

Comment: Seems like you want either a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) or a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: if you really want to generate variables in a loop you can use `globals()`, but it's usually a bad idea

Comment: @Dan Okay then not globals(). How do I use list or dict to do that?

Comment: Could you provide a more complete example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Dict example:

```
names = ['A', 'B', 'C']
my_dict = {}
for n, i in enumerate(names):
    name = 'name_{}'.format(n)
    my_dict[name] = i
```

Output:

```
{'name_0': 'A', 'name_1': 'B', 'name_2': 'C'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you get your `A, B, C` from, you can simply take them out of a list.

```
# or wherever your letters / whatever come from
import string
abc = string.ascii_uppercase

name0, name1, name2 = abc[0: 3]
print(name0)
print(name1)
print(name2)
```